# Are there any ways to get Fortnite after the mobile ban?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I used to play Fortnite. However, it has recently been banned on the app store and the mobile version is less fun compared to c2s4, with the main thing being that the normal version had a major superheroes update. I've tried to research this on youtube, but I got a ton of clickbait. I also tried to download it on a Windows PC, then send it to my iPad, but that failed too. What else can I do?

Edit: The solution below DOES NOT work. It's been patched.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...

Apple banned Fortnite from Appstore but you can still install it and play.

Did you installed Fortnite from AppStore using Apple ID? If yes then follow this quick guide:

1. Open AppStore
2. Tap your avatar to see your profile
3. Go to "purchased"
4. Then click on “My Purchases”
5. Search for "Fortnite" in the search tab. Download it when you find it.
6. Once downloaded, open the game and log in.

Remember that IOS devices are NOT getting superheroes update. It won't happen (at least for now).

Comment: No, this no longer works. Apple patched it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know.

Also I don't know if there's any possible method to obtain Fortnite. 

Downloading some APK and transfering it to iPad sounds like it could work but I'm not sure. Apple's closed system makes it only harder.